# How can I make a SSH tunnel command into a service on Windows 10?

Tags: service, windows-10, ssh-tunnel

I have a very simple command in powershell to start SSH tunnels:

```
ssh -N -L 28777:localhost:28778 myapp-db
```

What's the simplest way to make this a service, so I can run:

```
start-service db-tunnel
```

etc on Windows 10? I've read an [old article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt703436.aspx) on doing this and it involves using C#, which seems way too complex for such a simple task.

Comment: You could ["convert" your script into an exe](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PS2EXE-Convert-PowerShell-9e4e07f1) then use [NSSM](https://nssm.cc/)

Comment: You don't need the script at all. You just need to run the `ssh` executable with whatever parameters are appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell is not necessary. Here's one way:

1. Install the [Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657) package somewhere and get the files `instsrv.exe` and `srvany.exe`.
2. Use `srvany.exe` to create the service using the `ssh.exe` program and its parameters using the information in Microsoft help article [137890](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/137890/).

For example:

```
instsrv "SSH Server" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Resource Kit Tools\srvany.exe"
```

Of course, specify whatever service name you want and the path and filename of `srvany.exe`.

Next, use the registry editor to go to `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SSH Tunnel` (or whatever you named the service) in the registry and create a `Parameters` subkey. In the `Parameters` subkey create an `Application` value (`REG_SZ` type):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\ssh\ssh.exe
```

(or whatever - the path and filename to your ssh executable).

You can also create the values `AppDirectory` (`REG_SZ`) to specify the starting directory for the executable, and `AppParameters` (`REG_SZ`) to specify the parameters to the executable; e.g.:

```
-N -L 28777:localhost:28778 myapp-db
```

You can substitute the use of the NSSM tool mentioned by BenH in his comment if you prefer that tool and are allowed to use third-party software.

Answer (score -1):

To make something into a service, you would need to compile your script into an executable. This can be done via PS2EXE.

What may work just as well for you is making a function in powershell, `Start-DbTunnel`, and making that import into your powershell session on start. You can do this by loading functions in the foloowing path:

```
$PSprofilePath\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
```

or for the ISE

```
$PSprofilePath\Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1
```

Inside those files, I have

```
$PSprofilePath = "C:\Users\cknutson\Documents\WindowsPowershell"
$items = Get-ChildItem "$PSprofilePath\functions"
#Set-Location "$PSprofilePath\functions"
$items | ForEach-Object {
    . $_.FullName
}

Set-Location C:\
```

Any scripts containing functions, or otherwise will be run each time you open a powershell host.

Comment: I know what functions are and where my powershell profile is. 
The question is how to make a Powershell script into a service.

Comment: That is why I added the first part about making an executable to register as a service. If you just wanted to run the Powershell command you referenced to start the tunnel, then the function method would work very similar. You CAN'T directly run a Powershell script as a service.